# How do I simplify the code below when using grepl to replace every matched string?

Tags: r

I have column of file name (data$name) listed like:

```
aaa.doc
aaa.pptx
http://aaa
aaa.jpg
guide
some memo
...
```

I want to replace them with all types as far as I can, the name without a specific file type I would just mark it as "others".

When replacing the column of file name by the file type,I did this:

```
data$name[grepl("http",data$name,ignore.case = FALSE)]<-"web"
data$name[grepl("pptx",data$name,ignore.case = FALSE)]<-"ppt"
data$name[grepl("pdf",data$name,ignore.case = FALSE)]<-"pdf"
data$name[grepl("txt",data$name,ignore.case = FALSE)]<-"txt"
...
```

1.How to simplifiy this or is there any better way to do that?

2.How to replace the file names that didn't match any of the types I listed?

For ex: when the file name is **The guide** I would replace it with "others".

Thank you.

---

Please see my problem:

```
> d <- structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("aaa.doc", "aaa.jpg", "aaa.pptx", "guide", "http://aaa", "memo", "some"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -7L))
> d
        name
1    aaa.doc
2   aaa.pptx
3 http://aaa
4    aaa.jpg
5      guide
6       some
7       memo
> trans <- c(http = "web", pptx = "ppt", pdf = "pdf", txt = "txt")
> pat <- paste(names(trans), collapse = "|")  # http|pptx|pdf|txt
> strapply(as.character(d$name), pat, ~ trans[x], empty = "others", simplify = TRUE)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "pptx"

[[3]]
[1] "http"

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `data$name` with all relevant cases?

Comment: You could also change `data$name` into `factor` class and just change the `levels` as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `tidyverse` way it may look like below. You can add more options to `case_when()`

   library(tidyverse)

   data <- tibble(name=c('aaa.doc',  'aaa.pptx', 'aaa.txt', 'aaa.pdf', 
                         'http:////aaa',  'aaa.jpg',  'guide', 'some memo'))

   data <- data %>% 
     mutate(name= case_when(
       str_detect(tolower(name) , "http") ~ "web",
       str_detect(tolower(name), "pptx") ~ "ppt",
       str_detect(tolower(name), "pdf") ~ "pdf",
       str_detect(tolower(name), "txt") ~ "txt",
       str_detect(tolower(name), "guide") ~ "other",
       TRUE ~ 'unknown'   ))
2. TRUE should be last line to deal with all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

**1) strapply** Define a named vector `trans` that translates the matches to the types.   Then locate the `trans` names and translate each using `strapply`.

The first argument to `strapply` is the input character vector, the second is the pattern to match, the third is a function to apply to the matches here expressed using formula notation, the `empty` argument specifies what to use if there is no match and `simplify=TRUE` causes it to output a plain character vector rather than a list.

```
library(gsubfn)

trans <- c(http = "web", pptx = "ppt", pdf = "pdf", txt = "txt")

pat <- paste(names(trans), collapse = "|")  # http|pptx|pdf|txt
strapply(tolower(d$name), pat, ~ trans[x], empty = "others", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "others" "ppt"    "web"    "others" "others" "others" "others"
```

**2) Base R**  Using `trans` from above we can create a simple loop.

```
result <- result.ini <- tolower(d$name)
for(nm in names(trans)) result[ grepl(nm, result) ] <- trans[nm]
result[ result == result.ini ] <- "others"
result
## [1] "others" "ppt"    "web"    "others" "others" "others" "others"
```

**3) R Base - Reduce**  We can use `Reduce` in essentially the same way as the `for` loop but without an explicit loop:

```
Match <- function(result, nm) ifelse(grepl(nm, result), trans[nm], result)
out <- Reduce(Match, names(trans), init = tolower(d$name))
out[out == tolower(d$name)] <- "others"
out
## [1] "others" "ppt"    "web"    "others" "others" "others" "others"
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
d <- 
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("aaa.doc", 
"aaa.jpg", "aaa.pptx", "guide", "http://aaa", "memo", "some"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Please see my update , I still got a list when I used ' simplify = TRUE'. And can not replace correctly for the 'empty = "others"' .I hope you can check my code.Thank you!

Comment: I tried the code for (1) on both Windows and Linux and used R 3.5.3 and one earlier version of R on Windows and R 3.4.0 on Linux and they all gave the result shown in the answer.  Try it again on a fresh version of R.  Update R and your packages if old just in case (although as indicated it ran ok on an old verson of R for me).